# How to duplicate a document from one collection to another?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following models I work with:

```js
const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: String,
});

const User = model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = { userSchema, User };
```

And

```js
const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose');

const { userSchema } = require('./user');

const shopSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  address: String,
  contact: { type: String, unique: true },
  createdBy: userSchema,
  updatedBy: userSchema,
});

const Shop = model('Shop', shopSchema);

module.exports = { shopSchema, Shop };
```

Now the problem is: when I find a `user` from database and assigns it to `createdBy` and `updatedBy` fields, I get duplicate key error. Below is the code:

```js
const { Shop } = require('./shop');
const { User } = require('./user');

const user = await User.findById(id);
const shop = new Shop({ createdBy: user, updatedBy: user });
```

And below is the error:

```sh
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: database.shops index: updatedBy.email dup key: { updatedBy.email: "foo@bar.baz" }
```

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I already had another document in the collection where `createdAt.email` and `updatedAt.email` matched with the document I wanted to insert. For example:

```
_id: ObjectId("...")
name: "..."
address: "..."
contact: "..."
createdBy: Object
    _id: ObjectId("...")
    email: "foo@bar.baz"
updatedBy: Object
    _id: ObjectId("...")
    email: "foo@bar.baz"
```

was already there, and I tried to add another document with those fields' values being equal.

But this shouldn't be an issue here, since I'm not assigning that document to it's parent, rather in a different collection as sub-document. So it shouldn't worry about duplicate key problem. Now I need to know if there is any way to tell MongoDB/Mongoose not to worry about this problem.

### FIX:

Mongoose actually support index exclusion for nested sub-documents. Details can be found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema). All you have to do is to pass a 2nd parameter to the `Schema` constructor, an object where you specify not to index sub-paths. Like so:

```js
const shopSchema = new Schema(
  {
    //...
  },
  {
    excludeIndexes: true,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you define email like this

```
 email: { type: String, unique: true }
```

when a field is `unique`, mongoose indices it, when a filed is index, there should be only one number in collection, so

The first way: you should delete `unique: true` from email after that drop collection to remove indexes completely or use command for deleting index

the second way: put the use model in one filed, in `createdBy` or `updatedBy`,
when you put User in two fields in one collection, so created duplicate key

Comment: No that's not it. I have edited my answer, check that.